# Black Borders and Black Terminal - Upstart messing up on boot? Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, 16.04, unity, upstart

When I boot my computer, I can log in without problems, but when a window opens, I have black borders on windows and pop-ups and a black terminal.

I tried many things found on threads with the same problems, but still the same situation.

During my attempts to fix it, I noticed something:
I actually have two xsession-error files. One normal and one called x-session-errors.old

And when checking the content of the file :

**xsession-errors**

```
    openConnection: connect: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
cannot connect to brltty at :0
upstart: Le processus gnome-keyring-ssh main (1853) a été tué par le signal TERM
```

**xsession-errors.old**

```
openConnection: connect: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
cannot connect to brltty at :0
upstart: Le processus gnome-keyring-ssh main (2042) a été tué par le signal TERM
upstart: Le processus bamfdaemon main (2162) a été tué par le signal TERM
upstart: Le processus hud main (2194) a été tué par le signal HUP
upstart: Le processus unity-settings-daemon main (2196) a été tué par le signal HUP
upstart: Le processus unity-panel-service main (2209) a été tué par le signal HUP
upstart: Le processus indicator-bluetooth main (2280) a été tué par le signal TERM
upstart: Le processus gnome-session (Unity) main (2205) a été tué par le signal HUP
upstart: Le processus indicator-power main (2284) a été tué par le signal TERM
upstart: Le processus indicator-datetime main (2288) a été tué par le signal TERM
upstart: Le processus indicator-printers main (2293) a été tué par le signal TERM
upstart: Le processus indicator-session main (2295) a été tué par le signal TERM
upstart: Le processus indicator-application main (2319) a été tué par le signal TERM
upstart: Le processus indicator-application pre-stop (5796) a été tué par le signal TERM
upstart: Le processus gnome-session (Unity) pre-stop (5797) a été tué par le signal TERM
upstart: Déconnecté du bus D-Bus notifié
```

Brief translation :

```
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
```

And every line with `upstart` says that the process indicated was killed by  TERM or HUP signal

It finishes with a disconnection of D-Bus.

I'm not an expert, but it seems strange that upstart messes up with those processes.

Hope someone can find a solution so I can avoid reinstalling Ubuntu

PS : I actually did some compilations and exporting flags for a work in classes yesterday. I used sumo, ns.3-15 patched and ns-anim. Since I did compilation and configuration, I prefer to add it, who knows if it may help

Comment: We or I can't read french [as I believe that what it is] so please translate!

Comment: @George OP has provided translation of the errors

Comment: That's right, that's a fast but complete translation since there are almost only actions by upstart.

And thanks @Zanma for editing the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

The situation got worse when I couldn't even log in after rebooting, and after many tries of updating, upgrading, etc, I just tried to reinstall `ubuntu-desktop` for the second time and this did the trick (while I already did it, guess it was broken).

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: @Zanna Yep, with apt-get. While I'm pretty sure I did it, I guess the package was broken, and doing stuff like dpkg didn't fix it.